# Stop map being dragging Google Map V3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code from the google deveopers page:

http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Pw/5/

I am trying to stop users being able to drag the map in the window box. I found a way to do this but it uses var options = {} and this code doesn't exist in the code I am working with.

This site explains the options:
http://www.stupidiocy.com/development/using-the-google-maps-api-with-as3/

```
    private function onMapReady(event:Event):void
    {
        // Lock the map in every way possible
        _Map.disableDragging();
        _Map.disableScrollWheelZoom();
        _Map.disableControlByKeyboard();
        _Map.disableContinuousZoom();
        _Map.disableCrosshairs();
        _Map.mouseEnabled = false;
        _Map.mouseChildren = false;
        _Map.doubleClickEnabled = false;
```

Where should these options be put in the code? I cant make heads or tails or it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Maps API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

If you only want to stop the map being draggable, set draggable to false in the map options:

```
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      draggable:false
    };
```